# Why would a symbolic link intentionally point to a non-existent name?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I was browsing around in my machine and came across a dangling symbolic link that appeared to point to an IP address.

```
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 greatone  greatone       14 Oct 21 12:36 RunningChromeVersion -> 106.0.5249.119
```

Why would a program create such a link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the link isn't pointing to a file *at all* – it is being "creatively used" for some other purpose, most likely to act as a [lock file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files) that one of your programs uses to detect an already-running instance of the same program. The link target is just some arbitrary value that only the program itself understands; it isn't meant to exist as a real file.

Normal files are read or written in at least two steps: first the program calls `open()` and only then `read()`, leaving an unwanted opportunity for other programs to run between the two operations.

Although most operating systems provide functions to coordinate exclusive access to an open file, often this is limited to local files only – e.g. the Linux flock() historically hasn't worked all that well via NFS (which used to be very relevant on traditional Unix environments where /home would be shared via NFS or AFS from a central server), and there's no support for locking at all in SFTP (SSHFS).

On the other hand, the `symlink()` kernel function will create a link with a specified "target" value in just one step (i.e. it is an atomic operation), while the `readlink()` function will read its target in one call as well – the program always gets either a complete link target or a "not found" error with nothing in between. This leads to some programs using symlinks to detect when their config directory is already being used by another instance even on a different machine.

---

("106.0.5249.119" is not an IP address – as the file name suggests, it is a *version number* of Chrome in the "major.minor.build.revision" format that is extremely [common](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0#remarks) on Windows.

That said, you'll see the same trick being used by Firefox which *does* put IP addresses in its "lock" symlink targets.)

Answer (score 1):

The number `106.0.5249.119` is the release number of
[Chrome Stable Channel Update for Desktop](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2022/10/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_11.html)
from October 11, 2022.

What you have found is an internal Chrome file whose purpose is perhaps
to indicate to the installation its own version number.
It's not really a symlink, just perhaps Chrome abusing a little the
symlink feature for its own internal reasons.

It's unknown what purposes this file is serving and why Google thought
it was a good idea to do it like this. It could be used for too many
purposes for me to guess about.